# Apportion Ruby on Rails record updates by %

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, modulo

My aim is to tag each record based on ID, but want to properly apportion by:

- 50% of them will be tagged as "very good"
- 50% of them will be tagged
  as "good" or "ok"

In "good" and "ok", the aim is to tag 75% as "good" and 25% as "ok"

I don't have an issue tagging 50-50, cause I can check the ID if it's divisible by 2

Example:

```
if (feedback.id.modulo(2) == 0)
  // How can I apportion 75% will be tagged as "good" and 25% as "ok" here?
else
  feedback.update_attributes(status: "very good")
end
```

Is there a way in Ruby or Rails to allocate based on % conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (feedback.id.modulo(2) == 0)
  // How can I apportion 75% will be tagged as "good" and 25% as "ok" here?
else
  feedback.update_attributes(status: "very good")
end
```

It's good but with each feedback, you will excute 1 query to update, I think you can make it better

```
feed_back_ids = FeedBack.ids
FeedBack.where(id: feed_back_ids.pop(feed_back_ids.length/2)).update_all(status: "very good")
FeedBack.where(id: feed_back_ids.pop(feed_back_ids.length*3/4)).update_all(status: "good")
FeedBack.where(id: feed_back_ids).update_all(status: "ok")
```

If you want to make it randomly

```
feed_back_ids = FeedBack.ids.shuffle
FeedBack.where(id: feed_back_ids.pop(feed_back_ids.length/2)).update_all(status: "very good")
FeedBack.where(id: feed_back_ids.pop(feed_back_ids.length*3/4)).update_all(status: "good")
FeedBack.where(id: feed_back_ids).update_all(status: "ok")
```